# Is $\int_1^\infty x\cos(x^2 \ln x)\ dx$ convergent? Absolutely convergent?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Is
$$\int_1^\infty x \cos(x^2 \ln x)\ dx$$
convergent? Absolutely convergent?

Of course it's easy to understand that it doesn't absolutely converge, but is it convergent?

Comment: The alignment of the text in the integral looks odd.

Comment: Let $f(x)=x^2\ln x.$ Make the change of variables $x=f^{-1}(y).$ Think about Dirichlet's test.

Comment: @zhw. can't understandt your way, can you explain bit more please?

Comment: Hmm, if you integrate by parts with $v = \sin(x^2 \ln x)$ so $dv = (x + 2x \ln x) \cos(x^2 \ln x)$ and $u = \frac{1}{1 + 2 \ln x}$, then the integral is equal to $\frac{1}{1 + 2 \ln x} \sin(x^2 \ln x) + \int \frac{\sin(x^2 \ln x)}{x (1 + 2 \ln x)^2}\, dx$.  Doesn't quite answer the question yet but it's made progress in reducing the growth of the integrand.  Maybe another integration by parts with $v = -\cos(x^2 \ln x)$ would reduce it by enough more to conclude it converges?

Comment: Oh, actually, since $\int_\cdot^\infty \frac{1}{x (\ln x)^2} \, dx$ converges, I guess what's left after the first integration by parts is already absolutely convergent.